# Is there any meaningful performance difference between integer and string values for solr facets?

Tags: solr, facet

We're adding a facet field to our solr document set that defines which group it belongs to - the data comes out of mysql and I have a choice of putting the integer id (mysql pk) in the facet value in solr or putting the shortname (mysql varchar(32)) in the facet value.

Using the shortname has some appeal because we can go from user input (the shortname will be part of a url) straight to a solr query without a trip to mysql to find the pk.

However before I go that route I'd like to know if faceting on string fields is significantly different from faceting on integer values from a performance standpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use text fields for Faceting. You won't get the desired behaviour.

[SolrFacetingOverview](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) :-

> Because faceting fields are often specified to serve two purposes,
> human-readable text and drill-down query value, they are frequently
> indexed differently from fields used for searching and sorting:
>
> 1. They are often not tokenized into separate words
> 2. They are often not mapped into lower case
> 3. Human-readable punctuation is often not removed (other than double-quotes)
> 4. There is often no need to store them, since stored values would look much like indexed values and the faceting mechanism is used for
>    value retrieval.

Try to use String fields and it would be good enough without any overheads.